# Is Raven.Client.Authorization 1.0.960 package compatible with Raven.Client 1.0.972?

Tags: version, ravendb

The current version of the Raven.Client.Authorization is back a version from Raven.Client.  The new Raven.Clients allows you to use the latest Json.Net package and therefore RestSharp, ETC.

I hope to save some time / avoid a deep valley of frustration here.  Can 1.0.972 support the 1.0.960 Authorization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't sure if out of the box. Try use assembly redirect. If this is not working, you can get the source of build 972 from [this branch](https://github.com/fitzchak/ravendb/tree/v1-json.net) than compile the `Raven.Client.Authorization` for yourself, after you update the json.net reference there.

P.S. If your app is in development and will be for the next 2 months, I strongly recommend that you'll try out [v1.2](https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/tree/1.2), which already started the stabilization process.